# @font-face - why isn't the font being displayed?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Hi I've used css3s technique of `@font-face` to import the fonts to the site.
I've implemented the technique before on multiple sites so I'm not sure what is going on.

I even tried googles API to drive it. So, maybe it's a flaw in the code which I need a fresh pair of eyes to point on for me.

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "avant_gardebookregular";
    src: url("template/fonts/avantgardebook/avantgardebook-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'    );
    /*    src: url('/template2/fonts/avantgardebook/avantgardebook-webfont.eot?#iefix') format    ('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/template2/fonts/avantgardebook/avantgardebook-webfont.woff') format('woff')    ,
         url('/template2/fonts/avantgardebook/avantgardebook-webfont.eot') format (    'embedded-opentype'),
     url('/template2/fonts/avantgardebook/avantgardebook-webfont.    svg#avant_gardebookregular') format('svg');*/
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

p, a { font-family: "avant_gardebookregular" }
```

to see the website go to http://www.megareel.co.uk/services/
I.E (as expected doesn't work) but reliable ol' firefox is playing like IE. Google Chrome is how it should be!

Comment: Check the `Net` tab in your browser debugger, you have a lot of stuff 404'ing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the files aren't where you told your css they would be:

http://www.hydro-cleansing.com/minisites/template2/fonts/avantgardebook/avantgardebook-webfont.woff

gives 404

The .ttf files is there, which is why Chrome is right.

Additionally, there are other resources that are returning 404 errors:

- http://www.hydro-cleansing.com/minisites/template2/fonts/avantgardebook/avantgardebook-webfont.woff
- http://www.hydro-cleansing.com/minisites/template2/fonts/impact/impact-webfont.woff
- http://megareel.co.uk/services/template/slider/skins/fullwidth/skin.css
- http://www.hydro-cleansing.com/minisites/img/gallery/lightbox/close.png
- http://www.hydro-cleansing.com/minisites/img/gallery/lightbox/loading.gif
- http://www.hydro-cleansing.com/minisites/img/gallery/lightbox/prev.png
- http://www.hydro-cleansing.com/minisites/img/gallery/lightbox/next.png

And you have a JavaScript error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null main.js:40

Comment: Okay. But, chrome accepted it, so the url reference is correct! I've updated the links to the full address too (the one you've mentioned).

Comment: Chrome is using the eot version which is found.  If you remove the .eot line from your @font-face rule; Chrome breaks too, when it tries to use the .woff

Comment: I thought .ttf was supported by all major browsers [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp)

Comment: If all you had was the .ttf, maybe.  But your telling fire fox:
"Here is this font, in all these different formats. I prefer for you to use the eot. If you don't know that format, then use the woff. If you don't know that format..."  Problem is, FireFox is going, "I speak woff. I'll grab that. Request from server... and... oh, no good... Too bad."  You might not have to put up a woff file, you might just be able to remove the woff line. ;)

Comment: haha thanks. Yeah I've been racking my brain about it. It's strange that its chucking a 404 error cos the files are there unless there is a discrepancy with the words ... always a typo!